# html: resize text to keep same proportion with an image

Tags: html, css

we have a website in which in one of it's parts we can add an image to be shown plus a text. when we see the website in laptop which has a higher resolution, everything looks good but the same page in phone is shown in a way that the image is resized to fit the screen but the text size not.(text is bigger than the image). how can I solve that?

in desktop and smartphone:

[image: desktop]

[image: phone]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a smaller font on smaller screens, use the `vw` (viewport width) unit. Example:

```
body {
  font-size: 4vw;
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvw6oLqq/)

Answer (score 1):

As freestock.tk said, you can use `vw` units to have the font scale with the viewport width of your browser.

However, I'd suggest using `media queries` to set the font size because this ensures that your text never gets too big or too small.

Example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 999px) {
  body {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
  body {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

In the above example, if the viewport is at least 1000px wide, the font will be set to be `32px`. If it's anywhere between `500px` and `999px` it will be set to `24px`. Anything less than `499px` and it will be `18px`.

Check out this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wqk7ucjm/). Resize the width of the result window to see the effects.